# Does EX second impact performance in Redis?

Tags: performance, redis

I tried googling something similar , but wasn't habel to find something on the topic

I'm just curious, does it matter how big the number of seconds are set in a key impact performance in redis?

For example:

```
set mykey   "foobarValue"  EX  100    VS     set mykey   "foobarValue"  EX  2592000
```

Comment: It does NOT matter. A smaller timeout only makes the key expired sooner. It has nothing to do with performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this question, we need to see how Redis works.

Redis maintains tables of a key, value pair with an expiry time, so each entry can be translated to

```
<Key: <Value, Expiry>  >
```

There can be other metadata associated with this as well. During `GET`, `SET`, `DEL`, `EXPIRE` etc operations Redis calculates the hash of the given key(s) and tries to perform the operation. Since it's a hash table, it needs to prob during any operation, while probing it may encounter some expired keys.  If you have subscribed for "Keyspace notification" then notification would be sent and the given entry is removed/updated based on the operation being performed. It also does rehashing, during rehashing it might find expired keys as well. Redis also runs background tasks to cleanup expire keys, that means if TTL is too small then more keys would be expired, as this process is random, so more event would be generated.

https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/a92921da135e38eedd89138e15fe9fd1ffdd9b48/src/expire.c#L98

It does have a small performance issue when TTL is small since it needs to free the memory and fix some pointers. But it can so happen that you're running out of memory since expired keys are also present in the database. Similarly, if you use higher expiry time then the given key would present in the system for a longer time, that can create memory issue.

Setting smaller TTL has also more cache miss for the client application, so client will have performance issues as well.

Comment: thank you so much. i think i will put my session keys at least a week , a month seems excessive thanks again for taking  your time of the day to answer me  :)